# Referencing PivotTable Ranges in VBA for INDEX MATCH

Tags: excel, vba

is there a way to reference PivotTable ranges when using INDEX & MATCH in VBA?

My PivotTable is dynamic and the row/column sizes will change. Rather than having the lookup arrays in the formulas referencing bottom row of excel (1048576) and the last column (XFD), would it be possible to use .DataBodyRange and .DataRange?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say, but if the pivot table is using an OLAP data source it is easier to use the GETPIVOTDATA() worksheet function than INDEX() and MATCH().  The easiest way to use GETPIVOTDATA() is to edit a blank cell outside the pivot table, type = to start a formula, then click on a cell of interest in the pivot table and Excel will create a GETPIVOTDATA() call for you with the selection settings for the cell you clicked on, which will be robust enough to survive a pivot table refresh that causes different rows and columns to appear.  You can then get smart and edit the parameters of the GETPIVIOTDATA() (search for MDX for more info) to use formulas to retrieve different cells from your pivot table based on the row and column headings rather than sheet coordinates.  I would recommend doing as much of this as possible on the worksheet rather than in vba, then give your result cell(s) a name (named range) and use that name in vba, which is much easier to maintain.

Comment: Came across GETPIVOTDATA with some more searching, used it and worked perfectly, thanks!